# Rails strong parameters not recognizing my params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

I created a form to add a record to `:vote` model that belongs to `:article` model. As you can see below, the form to create the `:vote` record is in a `:article` view. In not using nested routes for these models so instead of using the `form_for` helper, I'm using plain `form_tags`. My problem is that `strong_parameters` is not allowing my hidden field through.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
<strong>Title:</strong>
<%= @article.title %> 
</p>

<p>
<strong>Body:</strong>
<%= @article.body %>
</p>

<p>
<strong>User:</strong>
 <%= @article.user_id %>
</p>

<%= form_tag("/vote/#{@article.id}", method: :post) do -%>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'vote[value]', 1 %>
<%= submit_tag 'Up vote' %>
<% end -%>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> 
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

As you can see in the controller code, I have white listed the the param and the log data show the post body coming in the right format for the parameters hash but it won't reach my create action.

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @vote = Vote.new(params[:strong_vote])
    @vote.user_id = current_user.id
    @vote.article_id = @article.id
    @vote.save
    redirect_to @article

end


private

def strong_vote
    params.require(:vote).permit(:value)
end


end

     Processing by VotesController#create as HTML Parameters:{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"Y6eBxpwGXGdT2toeUrxAlLW58Hj8Eux+SvoWeVUoYa8=","vote"=>{"value"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Up vote","id"=>"7"}
     Article Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE  "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
     User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE"users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
     Rendered text template (0.0ms)
     Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Here are my routes in case they may be helpful.

```
devise_for :users
root 'articles#index'

resources :articles

post '/vote/:id' => 'votes#create'
```

Update: I tried your answer doz87 but I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError in VotesController#create
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.

Extracted source (around line #5):
3
4
5
6
7
8

    def create
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @vote = Vote.new(:strong_vote)
        @vote.user_id = current_user.id
        @vote.article_id = @article.id
        @vote.save

Rails.root: /home/w/Folders/playground/ruby/voter

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/votes_controller.rb:5:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"AVKHgcsOwQhwWJGfSGQhIL1Lbr7yhSRaGKTrxuLcAuo=",
 "vote"=>{"value"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Up vote",
 "id"=>"7"}
```

Comment: Yeah your passing in a symbol to the Vote.new statement that requires a hash. If you used strong_vote without the colon then your passing in the parameter hash you defined in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because your not assigning anything to the new Vote. Params[:strong_vote] doesn't exist

```
@vote = Vote.new(params[:strong_vote])
```

You should write it like this:

```
@vote = Vote.new(strong_vote)
```

Also it's good practice to catch any errors from a failed save. You should wrap @vote.save in an if block incase something goes wrong.

```
if @vote.save
redirect_to @article
else
flash.now[:notice] = "Something went wrong while saving"
render 'new'
end
```

Comment: Actually..for some very weird reason..I deleted the strong param function and rewrote and it worked..but its written exactly the same....oh well Thanks @doz87